# How do i call third party API data via fastify?

Tags: api, fastify

I had a small node server and I use the framework fastify.

In one of my routes, I want to get the data from a third party API.

I tried the following snippet:

```
fastify.route({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://demo.api.com/api/v2/project/',
    handler: async function ({ params, body}, reply) {
        if (!body) return reply.send({ sucess: false })

        console.log('testing')
        console.log(body)

        return reply.send({ sucess: true })
    }
})
```

Unfortunately, I cannot call the URL by `get` because GET url's can only start with '/'.

How do i call a third pary api via fastify? do i need a extention?

Answer (score 2):

Proxy your http requests to another server, with fastify hooks.

here is the example in fastify-http-proxy

```js
server.register(require('fastify-http-proxy'), {
  upstream: 'http://my-api.example.com',
  prefix: '/api', // optional
  http2: false // optional
})
```

https://github.com/fastify/fastify-http-proxy/blob/master/example.js

Answer (score 1):

If you need to define a route (like `http://localhost:3000/`) that proxies another server you need to use [fastify-http-proxy](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-http-proxy).

Or if you need to call another endpoint and manage the response, there is the [`fastify.inject()`](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/master/docs/Testing.md#testing-with-http-injection) utility but it is designed for testing.

Anyway, I think the best approach is to use some HTTP client like [`got`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got)

```js
const got = require('got') // npm install got

fastify.get('/my-endpoint', async function (request, reply) {
  const response = await got('sindresorhus.com')
  console.log(response.body)
  // DO SOMETHING WITH BODY
  return { sucess: true }
})
```

Comment: {
    "statusCode": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "got is not defined"
}

Comment: I got the message: "got is not defined".

Comment: `npm install got`

Comment: exports.authentication = async (req, reply) => {
    try {
      const response = await got({
        method: 'POST',
        url: `https://url`,
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer 2HdfkjdfRg.XlgsfdkafjdfjfiWaTdnpg-OALdkfjfd'
        }
      })
      return response.body;
    } catch (err) {
      throw boom.boomify(err)
    }
}

Comment: I am doing this sir, is this correct? after npm i got, I still receive same error

Comment: Did you require it? `const got = require('got')`

Comment: I have update the answer to solve your issue